# Is it ok to have the same field names in abstract class and interface?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, interface

I am creating some classes and came to a point where I need to ask your opinion. Let's imagine such situation:

We have and abstract class `A`:

```
abstract class A {
  public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

And we have three classes implementing it `B`, `C` and `D`:

```
class B : A {
  public List<string> Comments {get; set;}
  public List<string> Categories {get; set;}
}

class C : A {
  public List<string> Categories {get; set;}
}

class D : A {
  public List<string> Comments {get; set;}
}
```

As you can see some properties are common and I want to extract them to another class/interface. So theoretically I could create following interfaces:

```
interface IWithCategories {
  List<string> Categories {get; set;}
}

interface IWithComments {
  List<string> Comments {get; set;}
}
```

And let `B`, `C` and `D` implement what they need. The problem is that when I would use `IWithCategories`, I will also need properties from `A`.

What would be a nice solution to this?

My idea is following:

1. I extract interface from `A`, called `IA`. `A` will of course implement `IA`.

   interface IA {
     int Id {get; set;}
   }

   abstract class A : IA {
     public int Id {get; set;}
   }
2. `IWithComments` and `IWithCategories` will extend `IA`:

   interface IWithCategories : IA {
     List Categories {get; set;}
   }

   interface IWithComments : IA {
     List Comments {get; set;}
   }
3. And then `B`, `C` and `D` can implements them:

   class B : A, IWithCategories, IWithComments {
     public List Comments {get; set;}
     public List Categories {get; set;}
   }

   class C : A, IWithCategories {
     public List Categories {get; set;}
   }

   class D : A,  {
     public List Comments {get; set;}
   }

I know that at this point classes `B`, `C` and `D` do not need to extend abstract class `A`, *BUT* it has some implementation that will be shared across all classes like equals, to string and some protected methods.

Is this approach acceptable?

*EDIT:*

I am writing an iOS app using Xamarin and I started of by having only classes `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. And some point I have encountered a situation where I am creating a ViewController that should be used for all classes that have `Comments` field and this is when I came up with idea of extracting interfaces. But then, I also need to call a web service and I need `Id` declared on `A` and now I am thinking how to handle this. Hope it helps.

Comment: It is ok, but if you want a different implementation, you can implement the interface explicitly.

Comment: I IS acceptable in general, but knowing your goal for this structure will help a lot.

Comment: Updated my post. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, Why do the interfaces need setters, I'll assume they don't. Do the interfaces need to expose `List<string>` instead of `IList<string>`, I'll assume not. Then you have these interface definitions.

```
public interface IWithCategories {
  IList<string> Categories { get; }
}

public interface IWithComments {
  IList<string> Comments { get; }
}
```

Now, if these interfaces are `public` you can't stop them being implemented by whoever chooses to do so. If you keep them `internal` only your assembly will be able to use them.

If you'd like `abstract class A` to implement these interfaces you can define it as such,

```
public abstract class A : IWithCategories, IWithComments
{
    abstract public int Id { get; }

    abstract public IList<string> Categories { get; }

    abstract public IList<string> Comments { get; }
}
```

How inheritors of `A` implement `IWithCategories`, `IWithComments` and the `Id` property cannot be defined in the contract defined by the interface.

However, you might envisage an implementation along these lines,

```
public class B : A
{
    private readonly int id;
    private readonly List<string> categories;
    private readonly List<string> comments;

    public B(
            int id,
            IEnumerable<string> categories
            IEnumerable<string> comments)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.categories = (categories ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>()).ToList();
        this.comments = (comments ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>()).ToList();
    }

    public override int Id
    {
        get { return this.id; }
    }

    public override IList<string> Categories
    {
        get { return this.categories; }
    }

    public override IList<string> Comments
    {
        get { return this.comments; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding pint 1:

This is fine in case you have more than one implementation for `IA` interface in case the abstract class is unique. Then there is no reason to create additional abstract layer. Especially when the implementation of abstract class base partially on that method.

Regarding point 2:

`IWithCategories : IA` and `IWithComments : IA`

You brake hire the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Note also the naming could reflect more .NET conventions `ICategorizable` and `ICommentable`. Those are not valid words but express the idea.

Also remember that interfaces should provide some functionality. Having setters in then will open your API as Jodreli wrote.

Regarding point 3:

At this point is really hard to advice as your examples are really abstract and vague. The final implementation could vary on the reason those classes B,C and D has.

A tip here is that you should [promote the composition rather than inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and also assure that classes B C and D really are good examples of A concept.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "promote composition"?

Comment: @BartoszCichecki by this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance